# SharePoint 2010 upload files from usercontrol

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, file-upload

I have a user control to upload files in SharePoint document library

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fileBrowse" runat="server" />
 <asp:Button ID="fileUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Files" OnClick="fileUpload_Click" />
```

code behind (Client Object Model):

```
  protected void fileUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileBrowse.HasFile)
        {
            string filename = fileBrowse.PostedFile.FileName;
            String fileToUpload = @filename;
            String sharePointSite = ".../GxAIM/";
            String documentLibraryName = "Shared Documents";

            using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))
            {
                using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
                        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);

                    SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

                    // Prepare to upload
                    Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
                    String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
                    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

                    // Upload document
                    SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

                    // Commit 
                    myLibrary.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

when I am on dev machine (remote connection) it works fine, but when I am on local machine with same user credentials, I can upload with the OOTB method on the shared library but if I browse from the user control then I click upload, it loads the documents til 100% then tell me :

```
[FileNotFoundException: File not found.]
```

I noticed that In local machine for line :

string filename = fileBrowse.PostedFile.FileName; I have just filename

but in dev machine I have all the path which is correct.

Comment: Saving the file physically onto server and than working on the same helped me resolve my issue.